# Почему в скрипте на Button не могу применить interactable?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SelectLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button[] Buttons;
    int LevelInLock;

    void Start()
    {
        LevelInLock = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelComplete", 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            Buttons[i].interactable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Просто ошибка: `Ошибка    CS1061  "Button" не содержит определения "interactable", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "interactable", принимающий тип "Button" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).`

Comment: Лично у меня ваш код не вызывает никаких проблем. Возможно дело не в скрипте, а в проекте. Скиньте, пожалуйста, скриншот инспектора с этим скриптом и хотя бы одной кнопки

Comment: @МаксимФисман, да так и было я уже разобрался. Был скрипт с таким же название как у переменной.

Comment: на вопрос нужно дать ответ, чтобы он закрылся, и это было видно всем. Если хотите, ответ на вопрос могу дать я, главное, чтобы ответ был принят, иначе он будет висеть открытым

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка из-за того что название переменной совпадало со скриптом, который был создан до этого.